# Google maps crashes in react native with error glCreateShader failed with return value 0

Tags: react-native, google-maps, opengl-es, react-native-maps

I am using rect-native-maps in my android application and it is crashing randomly on the production app with below error

```
Fatal Exception: m.evv: glCreateShader failed with return value 0and GL error code 0
GL info log: 
<no info log>
Shader vert source: 
<unused source>
       at m.esv.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610103@233610101065.570495220.570495220:71)
       at m.esv.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610103@233610101065.570495220.570495220:4)
       at m.etr.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610103@233610101065.570495220.570495220:32)
       at m.ets.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610103@233610101065.570495220.570495220:6)
       at m.esq.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@233610103@233610101065.570495220.570495220:119)
```

How can i fix this?